# What's the difference between priority queue(=heap) and sorting?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, priority-queue, heap

[406. Queue Reconstruction by Height](https://leetcode.com/problems/queue-reconstruction-by-height/)
The best answer to the above problem is this.

```py
class Solution:
    def reconstructQueue(self, people: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        heap = []
        for person in people:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (-person[0], person[1]))

        result = []
        while heap:
            person = heapq.heappop(heap)
            result.insert(person[1], [-person[0], person[1]])
        return result
```

The above method is a **priority queue** method.

On the other hand, the method using **sorting** is this.

```py
class Solution:
    def reconstructQueue(self, people: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        people.sort(key = lambda x:(x[0],-x[1]))
        result = []
        while people:
            person = people.pop()
            result.insert(person[1], [person[0],person[1]])
        return result
```

big-O is similar. **But I don't know why we should use a more complex priority queue. What are the advantages of priority queue over sorting?**

Comment: There's no real reason to use a priority queue here. (I would be surprised if *either* of these solutions is asymptotically optimal. These are both worst-case O(n^2), and it seems like an O(n log n) solution should be possible.)

Comment: *"But I don't know why we should use a more complex priority queue."* There's a fallacy in the question; you're assuming that managing a priority queue is more "complex" than running a sorting algorithm. First, it's not clear what "complex" means in this context. Second, have you heard of heapsort? It's a relatively simple sorting algorithm that relies on a priority queue. By comparison, I would say Timsort (which is the algorithm called when you use `list.sort` in python) is more "complex" than heapsort.

Comment: In a comment (to an answer) you mention you have an `insert` operation. That will make all the difference. If this is the case, I suggest you add that information (with code) in your question, as it will be essential in answering the question.

Comment: @Stef I thought `list.sort` was an intuitive and concise code to see. I don't understand that heapsort is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there's little difference.

The use of the priority queue and the call to `.sort()` do essentially the same thing -- they order the elements to be processed in decreasing order of height value.

As the comment points out, the runtime is dominated by the calls to `.insert()`. Insertion to an arbitrary index in a list takes worst-case linear time, and with n insertions, your code runs in O(n^2) time. So the mechanism to order the elements for processing matters little in this case (with respect to asymptotic performance).

Comment: So there's no difference in priority queue and alignment. I'll have to think of a way to replace  `insert()`. Thanks